# Most efficient way for rendering string templates using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, performance, rendering

I need to render a template string in my node.js application. I don't want to use Jade, Ejs, React or similar libraries. I want to do it using plain javascript for various reason. I wonder which is the most efficient way to do it, i have thought two ways.

An example template string could be:

```
<html>
<head></head>

 <body>
   <div>{{data1}}</div>
   <span>{{data2}}</span>
 </body> 

</html>
```

I need to replace `{{data1}}` and `{{data2}}` with some data.
I am wondering if it's a better solution in terms of performance using regexes and calling multiple times:

`templateString.replace(/{{data1}}/, data)`

or cycling each character of the string and perform rendering inside a for loop in the following way, without using regexes:

`for(i = 0; i < templateString.length; i++) {//binding logic}`

I don't know how `replace` method works at the lower level, so i wonder if performing it multiple time is worse in performance than cycling once all characters of my string.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: I'm guessing the for loop is marginally faster at finding a match, but you still have to replace something, and using a regex is so much simpler for things like this, so that's what I would use, or not really, I'd use EJS instead of inventing the wheel all over again, it does exactly this using a regex.

Comment: why dont you butcher it from jquery tmpl ?
 trim(markup)
    .replace(/([\\'])/g, "\\$1")
    .replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
    .replace(/\$\{([^\}]*)\}/g, "{{= $1}}")
    .replace(/\{\{(\/?)(\w+|.)(?:\(((?:[^\}]|\}(?!\}))*?)?\))?(?:\s+(.*?)?)?(\(((?:[^\}]|\}(?!\}))*?)\))?\s*\}\}/g,
    function (all, slash, type, fnargs, target, parens,

Comment: because i suppose that each replace should cycle the whole string in background to find the match, and i want a faster way that cycle the whole string just once! @MhammadChehab

Comment: Okay so i thought you want something quick and dirty ! @Morrisda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a String extension I use for 'templating', without the need for regular expressions. Maybe it's of use to you. It should be faster than regex/replace, cf [**this test**](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/16/hand-written-lexer-in-javascript-compared-to-the-regex-based-ones)

```js
String.prototype.format = format;

var str = ('<div>This is {0}</div><span>And here we have {1}</span>' +
           '<span>{2} I repeat {0} or {1}</span>').replace(/</g,'&lt;');

log('<b>the original string</b>: ', str);
log('<b>the formatted string</b>: ', 
     str.format('<i>data1</i>', '<i>data2</i>','&nbsp;--'));
log('<b>back to html</b>: ',
     str.replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
     .format('<i>data1</i>', '<i>data2</i>','&nbsp;--'));

log('or just ... hello {0}'.format('world!'));

function log() {
  var args = Array.apply([], {length: arguments.length})
             .map( function (v, i) { return this[i]; }, arguments);
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += '<p>{0}</p>'.format(args.join(''));
  
}

// this function parses tokens with pattern {\d+} within a string
function format() {
  return function (text, args) {
    var len       = text.length,
        index     = 0,
        parsed    = '',
        currToken = ''
    ;
    while (index < len) {
      if (text[index] === '{' && !isNaN( parseInt(text[index + 1],10) ) ) {
                index += 1;
                currToken = '';
                var istoken = true;
                while (text[index] !==  '}' ) {
                  if ( isNaN( parseInt(text[index],10) ) ) {
                    istoken = false;
                    break;
                  }
                  currToken += text[index];
                  index += 1;
                }
                parsed += istoken && args[+currToken]
                          || '{' + currToken + (text[index] || '');
      }else {
        parsed += text[index];
      }
      index += 1;
    }
    return parsed;
  }(this, arguments);
};
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px normal verdana, arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A common approach to this is to handle placeholders in the `replace` callback:

```
 markup = template.replace(/{{(.+?)}}/g, function(_, placeholder) {
      // return data for the placeholder
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler is to use JavaScript **string interpolation**:

```
const resultTemplate = (data) => `
<div>${he.encode(data.param)}</div>
`

const html = resultTemplate(data);
```

NOTE: for encoding i've used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/he

**Or if you need something more:**
https://ejs.co/